# understanding a pathfinding algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been studying a pathfinding algorithm and for the most part I understand a lot of it but the part that's still confusing me is how the proper path is being set.

It prints out

```
[ 'East' ]
[ 'South' ]
[ 'East', 'East' ]
[ 'South', 'South' ]
[ 'East', 'East', 'East' ]
[ 'South', 'South', 'South' ]
[ 'South', 'South', 'South', 'East' ]
[ 'South', 'South', 'South', 'East', 'East' ]
[ 'South', 'South', 'South', 'East', 'East', 'North' ]
```

where / how in the code does it decide, hey [ 'East', 'East', 'East' ] isn't working out anymore and discards it from the path array?

```js
// Start location will be in the following format:
// [distanceFromTop, distanceFromLeft]
var findShortestPath = function(startCoordinates, grid) {
  var distanceFromTop = startCoordinates[0];
  var distanceFromLeft = startCoordinates[1];

  // Each "location" will store its coordinates
  // and the shortest path required to arrive there
  var location = {
    distanceFromTop: distanceFromTop,
    distanceFromLeft: distanceFromLeft,
    path: [],
    status: 'Start'
  };

  // Initialize the queue with the start location already inside
  var queue = [location];

  // Loop through the grid searching for the goal
  while (queue.length > 0) {
    // Take the first location off the queue
    var currentLocation = queue.shift();
    // Explore North
    var newLocation = exploreInDirection(currentLocation, 'North', grid);
    if (newLocation.status === 'Goal') {
      return newLocation.path;
    } else if (newLocation.status === 'Valid') {
      queue.push(newLocation);
    }

    // Explore East
    var newLocation = exploreInDirection(currentLocation, 'East', grid);
    if (newLocation.status === 'Goal') {
      return newLocation.path;
    } else if (newLocation.status === 'Valid') {
      queue.push(newLocation);
    }

    // Explore South
    var newLocation = exploreInDirection(currentLocation, 'South', grid);
    if (newLocation.status === 'Goal') {
      return newLocation.path;
    } else if (newLocation.status === 'Valid') {
      queue.push(newLocation);
    }

    // Explore West
    var newLocation = exploreInDirection(currentLocation, 'West', grid);
    if (newLocation.status === 'Goal') {
      return newLocation.path;
    } else if (newLocation.status === 'Valid') {
      queue.push(newLocation);
    }
  }

  // No valid path found
  return false;

};

// This function will check a location's status
// (a location is "valid" if it is on the grid, is not an "obstacle",
// and has not yet been visited by our algorithm)
// Returns "Valid", "Invalid", "Blocked", or "Goal"
var locationStatus = function(location, grid) {
  var gridSize = grid.length;
  var dft = location.distanceFromTop;
  var dfl = location.distanceFromLeft;

  if (location.distanceFromLeft < 0 ||
      location.distanceFromLeft >= gridSize ||
      location.distanceFromTop < 0 ||
      location.distanceFromTop >= gridSize) {

    // location is not on the grid--return false
    return 'Invalid';
  } else if (grid[dft][dfl] === 'Goal') {
    return 'Goal';
  } else if (grid[dft][dfl] !== 'Empty') {
    // location is either an obstacle or has been visited
    return 'Blocked';
  } else {
    return 'Valid';
  }
};


// Explores the grid from the given location in the given
// direction
var exploreInDirection = function(currentLocation, direction, grid) {

  var newPath = currentLocation.path.slice();
  newPath.push(direction);

  var dft = currentLocation.distanceFromTop;
  var dfl = currentLocation.distanceFromLeft;

  if (direction === 'North') {
    dft -= 1;
  } else if (direction === 'East') {
    dfl += 1;
  } else if (direction === 'South') {
    dft += 1;
  } else if (direction === 'West') {
    dfl -= 1;
  }

  var newLocation = {
    distanceFromTop: dft,
    distanceFromLeft: dfl,
    path: newPath,
    status: 'Unknown'
  };
  newLocation.status = locationStatus(newLocation, grid);

  // If this new location is valid, mark it as 'Visited'
  if (newLocation.status === 'Valid') {
    grid[newLocation.distanceFromTop][newLocation.distanceFromLeft] = 'Visited';
  }

  return newLocation;
};


// OK. We have the functions we need--let's run them to get our shortest path!

// Create a 4x4 grid
// Represent the grid as a 2-dimensional array
var gridSize = 4;
var grid = [];
for (var i=0; i<gridSize; i++) {
  grid[i] = [];
  for (var j=0; j<gridSize; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = 'Empty';
  }
}

// Think of the first index as "distance from the top row"
// Think of the second index as "distance from the left-most column"

// This is how we would represent the grid with obstacles above
grid[0][0] = "Start";
grid[2][2] = "Goal";

grid[1][1] = "Obstacle";
grid[1][2] = "Obstacle";
grid[1][3] = "Obstacle";
grid[2][1] = "Obstacle";

console.log(findShortestPath([0,0], grid));
```

Comment: For every location it keeps the `path` how it got there, then it continues searching from there on. I don't think that this gets the shortest path though